# Can not use executeQuery()

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm making an application to get data from Database , But I can't use `executeQuery` in my code.
This is exception of my code : `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement cannot be cast to java.beans.Statement
    at Database.main(Database.java:28)`
Where is the problem?

```
Connection MyconObj=null;
Statement MystateObj =null;
ResultSet MyresObj = null;


try {
    MyconObj = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/students", "root", "root");
    MystateObj = (Statement) MyconObj.createStatement();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM ROOT.INFORMATION";
    ResultSet MyresObj = MystateObj.executeQuery(query);


   while(MyresObj.next()){
       int id = MyresObj.getInt("id");
       String name = MyresObj.getString("name");
       String lastname = MyresObj.getString("lastname");
       System.out.println(id + "" + name + "" + lastname);

   }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what is the exception message?

Comment: What do you mean by 'can't use executeQuery in my code.' ? Are you getting an exception at runtime?

Comment: Please provide more information, like the error or exception stacktrace. And I strongly suggest that you start using the Java naming conventions (variables and fields starting with a lowercase letter: that makes your code more readable for people familiar with those conventions (ie most Java developers).

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement cannot be cast to java.beans.Statement
 at Database.main(Database.java:28)

Comment: @RannLifshitz Yes!

Comment: Remove the import for `Statement` and import the other class

Comment: Remove the cast and make sure that you import `java.sql.Statement`, not `java.beans.Statement`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it worked :)))) thankss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic example of how classes with the same name can cause confusion and runtime exceptions:

```
MystateObj = (Statement) MyconObj.createStatement();
```

The imports used by the implementation have not been included in the OP code, however, based on the thrown exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement cannot be cast to java.beans.Statement
```

The `Statement` class used in the cast is `java.beans.Statement`, which has probably been imported. The object which has been returned by `MyconObj.createStatement()` is of the type `org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement` and this causes the casting exception during runtime - the returned Object is an extension of `java.sql.Statement`, as mentioned in the comments above (by [Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel)).

The import of the `Statement` is correct but from the wrong library. This can easily occur when using IDEs which allow auto import generation (when more then one class matches the used class name, a drop-down list is displayed for possible imports. Selecting the wrong import is a common event, unfortunately).